# How to plot a heatmap using seaborn or matplotlib?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataframe that I am trying to visualize into a heatmap, I used matplotlib to make a heatmap but it is showing data that is not apart of my dataframe.

I've tried to create a heatmap using matplotlib from an example I found online and changed the code to work for my data. But on the left side of the graph and top of it there are random values that are not apart of my data and I'm not sure how to remove them.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import StringIO

url = 'http://mcubed.net/ncaab/seeds.shtml'

#Getting the website text
data = requests.get(url).text

#Parsing the website
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")

#Create an empty list
dflist = []

#If we look at the html, we don't want the tag b, but whats next to it
#StringIO(b.next.next), takes the correct text and makes it readable to 
pandas
for b in soup.findAll({"b"})[2:-1]:
    dflist.append(pd.read_csv(StringIO(b.next.next), sep = r'\s+', header 
= None))

dflist[0]

#Created a new list, due to the melt we are going to do not been able to 
replace
#the dataframes in DFList
meltedDF = []

#The second item in the loop is the team number starting from 1
for df, teamnumber in zip(dflist, (np.arange(len(dflist))+1)):

    #Creating the team name
    name = "Team " + str(teamnumber)

    #Making the team name a column, with the values in df[0] and df[1] in 
our dataframes
    df[name] = df[0] + df[1]

    #Melting the dataframe to make the team name its own column
    meltedDF.append(df.melt(id_vars = [0, 1, 2, 3]))

# Concat all the melted DataFrames
allTeamStats = pd.concat(meltedDF)

# Final cleaning of our new single DataFrame
allTeamStats = allTeamStats.rename(columns = {0:name, 2:'Record', 3:'Win 
Percent', 'variable':'Team' , 'value': 'VS'})\
                           .reindex(['Team', 'VS', 'Record', 'Win 
Percent'], axis = 1)

allTeamStats
#Graph visualization Making a HeatMap
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"]
x=["16","15","14","13","12","11","10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"]
winp = []
for i in x:
    lst = []
    for j in y:
        percent = allTeamStats.loc[(allTeamStats["Team"]== 'Team '+i) &\
                                    (allTeamStats["VS"]== "vs.#"+j)]['Win 
Percent'].iloc[0]
        percent = float(percent[:-1])
        lst.append(percent)
    winp.append(lst)
winpercentage= np.array([[]])

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(18,18))
im= ax.imshow(winp, cmap='hot')
# We want to show all ticks...
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(y)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(x)))

# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_xticklabels(y)
ax.set_yticklabels(x)

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

#  Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
         text = ax.text(j, i, winp[i][j],
                        ha="center", va="center", color="red")

ax.set_title("Win Percentage of Each Matchup", fontsize= 40)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(winp)
plt.colorbar(heatmap)
ax.set_ylabel('Seeds', fontsize=40)
ax.set_xlabel('Seeds', fontsize=40)
plt.show()
```

The results I get are what I want except for the two lines that are on the left side and top of the heatmap. I'm unsure what these values are coming from and to easier see them I used cmap= 'hot' to show the values that are not supposed to be there. If you could help me fix my code to plot it correctly or plot an entire new heatmap using seaborn (my TA told me to try using seaborn but I've never used it yet) with my data. Anything helps Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if you copy paste the code there's going to be a couple of errors because some of the notes got indented to a new line just add a # to it :)

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid your question is too big and this will detain other people from answering it. Make sure to read [How to ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the "Help others reproduce the problem" section and then you will be good (:

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit is this line: `im= ax.imshow(winp, cmap='hot')` in your code. Delete it and try again. Basically, anything that you plotted after that line was laid over what that line created. The left and top "margins" were the only parts of the image on the bottom that you could see.